# Why is this COMMENTED piece of code, <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>, not allowing my ROR app to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less-rails

I'm in the process of getting Twitter-rails-bootstrap GEM up and running on my Windows OS.

The load error is below:

```
    cannot load such file -- less
       (in C:/Sites/cardMS/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your application.css file here Also to comment some rails code your need append hash although it is in html comment block like `<%#= stylesheet_link_tag “application”, :media => “all” %>`

Comment: that's not commented...

Comment: If you're trying to comment out the generated stylesheet that is how you do it.

Comment: Its not comment/uncomment part. its the less error i am having problems with. and it points to <%#= stylesheet_link_tag “application”, :media => “all” %> this piece of code as being the issue

Comment: You need to post your stylesheet then. The error could be in your stylesheet or in how it processes everything into application.css. Remove your created style sheet and see if it processes everything else fine. If it doesn't then your stylesheet may not be the problem/only problem.

Answer (score 2):

To comment some rails code you need append hash although it is in html comment block.

So change

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag “application”, :media => “all” %>
```

to

```
<%#= stylesheet_link_tag “application”, :media => “all” %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested Nitin's answer in a sample app and looked it up. Indeed all you need to do to comment any erb is place a hash sign after the opening '<%' tag. I suppose the erb parser doesn't care about normal ruby comments as those too can have dynamic parts. This indeed happens when you generate a scaffold and the commented  route "#get /posts/1" shows the correct resource. Rails generators do support this feature with templates.

```
<%= not commented blah %>

  becomes

<%#= commented blah %>
```